# Printing data with Thermal printer (TSC TTP 244 pro)

Tags: javascript, html, thermal-printer

I am creating a table whose QR is also ready and showing it as you can see in the mentioned image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyERO.png)
Using these method:-

```
const data = [["1.3","NORMAL OD","FINOTEX","5376","13.040"],["1.3","NORMAL OD","FINOTEX","5376","13.040"],["1.3","NORMAL OD","FINOTEX","5376","13.040"],["1.3","NORMAL OD","FINOTEX","5376","13.040"]]

    let table = `<table border="1">

       <thead>

       <tr>

       <th>Size</th>

       <th>OD</th>

       <th>Brand</th>

       <th>Weight</th>

       </tr>

       </thead>

     <tbody>`;
let total_weight = 0;

        data.forEach(element => {total_weight += parseFloat(element[3]);

            table += `

            <tr>

          <td>${element[0]}</td>

          <td>${element[1]}</td>

          <td>${element[2]}</td>

          <td>${parseFloat(element[3])}</td>

          </tr>

                      `

                    });

             table += `

             <tr>

          <td colspan=3>Total Weight</td><td>${total_weight}</td>

           </tr>

           </tbody>

           </table>

                       `       

       

             document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = table;
```

The problem is:-
I have a TSC TTP 244 Pro printer.  I want to print this entire div (table and qr code both) using this printer as shown in the image with size = 75mm×50mm

How can i do this with my connected thermal printer(TSC TTP 244 pro) via USB?

Comment: `mm` is a valid css unit. You could use this to help style your layout.

Comment: Is there a relationship between what you want to do and the information written in the question article? There are so many steps required to achieve this that the question may be meaningless. Why not check out the device drivers, manuals, specifications, SDK, etc. listed on the vendor's product information page? [TTP Series 4-Inch Performance Desktop Printers](https://usca.tscprinters.com/en/products/ttp-series-4-inch-performance-desktop-printers)